# polling server after POST 201 CREATED c#

Tags: c#, rest, timer, server, polling

I've probably made a really silly mistake, I am able to make a successful POST request to server. I am also able to get a response from server 201 as well as being able to view the `json("requestid")`. I am able to deserialize the JSON and parse `requestid` as a string (`public string requestID`). I have a timer (`timer1`) set up to poll the server every 1 second, the polling should start successfully if 201 created and does. However the problem I am having is that it does not include the `requestid`. Would someone be able to advise and tell me where I had gone wrong please?

```
namespace RestAPI
{
    public enum httpVerb
    {
        GET,
        POST,
        PUT,
        DELETE
    }


    class RESTAPI
    {
        public string endPoint { get; set; }
        public httpVerb httpMethod { get; set; }
        public string userPassword { get; set; }
        public int sendAmount { get; set; }
        public string location { get; set; }

        public string requestId { get; set; }



        public RESTAPI()
        {
            endPoint = string.Empty;
            httpMethod = httpVerb.GET;
            userPassword = string.Empty;
            //requestId = string.Empty; 

        }

        public string makeRequest()
        {
            string strResponseValue = string.Empty;
            string result = string.Empty;



            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(endPoint);
            request.Method = httpMethod.ToString();
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.Accept = "application/connect.v1+json";

            String username = "mokhan";
            String encoded = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(username + ":" + userPassword));
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);

            if(httpMethod == httpVerb.POST)
            {
                using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
                {
                    string json = "{\"transactionType\":\"SALE\"," + "\"amount\":" + sendAmount + "," +
                                  "\"currency\":\"GBP\"}";

                    streamWriter.Write(json);
                    streamWriter.Flush();
                    streamWriter.Close();
                }



                HttpWebResponse responseback = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                //string result;
                using (StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(responseback.GetResponseStream()))
                {

                    result = rdr.ReadToEnd();
                }


                if (responseback.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Created)
                {
                    dynamic jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result);
                    requestId = jsonObj.requestId.ToString();
                    return requestId;
                }
                return result;

            }

            HttpWebResponse response = null;

            try
            {                
                response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                       if (responseStream != null)
                          {
                            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                            {
                                strResponseValue = reader.ReadToEnd();
                            }
                        }   
                    }                 
                }


            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }

            finally
                {
                    if (response != null)
                    {
                        ((IDisposable)response).Dispose();
                    }
                }

                return strResponseValue;
            }

    }
}
```

This code below shows my POST and GET requests to server, I have added the timer method to start in my POST request after I get a response and have added the code for polling in my timer method. I have also set string `transactionid = rclient.requestId;` and the called on `rclient.endPoint = "https://" + txtBox.Text + "/pac" + "/terminals/" + txtBox3.Text + "/transactions/" + transactionid;` to poll the server every 1 second but for some reason it's not picking up `transactionid`.

```
namespace RestAPI
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void go_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RESTAPI rclient = new RESTAPI();
            rclient.endPoint = "https://" + txtBox.Text + "/pac" + "/terminals/" + txtBox3.Text;
            rclient.userPassword = txtbox2.Text;
            debugOutput("REQUEST SENT");
            string strResponse = string.Empty;
            strResponse = rclient.makeRequest();

            debugOutput(strResponse);
        }

        private void debugOutput(string strDebugText)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(strDebugText + Environment.NewLine);
                txtBoxResponse.Text = txtBoxResponse.Text + strDebugText + Environment.NewLine;
                txtBoxResponse.SelectionStart = txtBoxResponse.TextLength;
                txtBoxResponse.ScrollToCaret();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(ex.Message, ToString() + Environment.NewLine);

            }
        }

        private void txtBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Test_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RESTAPI rclient = new RESTAPI();
            rclient.httpMethod = httpVerb.POST;
            rclient.sendAmount = Convert.ToInt32(amount.Text);
            rclient.endPoint = "https://" + txtBox.Text + "/pac" + "/terminals/" + txtBox3.Text + "/transactions";
            rclient.userPassword = txtbox2.Text;

            debugOutput("REQUEST SENT");

            string strResponse = string.Empty;
            strResponse = rclient.makeRequest();
            debugOutput(strResponse);


            timer1.Start();


    }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            RESTAPI rclient = new RESTAPI();
            rclient.httpMethod = httpVerb.GET;
            string transactionid = rclient.requestId;
            rclient.endPoint = "https://" + txtBox.Text + "/pac" + "/terminals/" + txtBox3.Text + "/transactions/" + transactionid; 
            debugOutput("REQUEST SENT");
            string strResponse = string.Empty;
            strResponse = rclient.makeRequest();
            debugOutput(strResponse);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A normal response from server is 200 Done.  You are looking for HttpStatusCode.Created

Comment: the server i am using gives a 201 response after i send the Post request. it provides me with the location of the created resource as well as the requestid in json, i can grab the request id and convert to string, its just when i start the timer it doesnt pick up the transactionid. i set a breakpoint and the transaction id is null for some reason

Comment: You have two rclient defined inside the methods.  Have rclient defined in global space so it is shared between the methods.  You may need to lock the reading of the class so you do not have conflicts.  I would create a read/write method that is static and put the lock in the the method so you are not reading and writing at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just solved the issue, in my public class RESTAPI, i un-commented this
            //requestId = string.Empty; 
once done, i was able to pick up the request ID as a string and then call it in my timer 
string transactionid = rclient.requestId;